# Serving static files from a CDN with Catalyst

Tags: perl, cdn, catalyst

I'm trying to serve all static files (js, css, images) from a CDN instead of the /static folder. I started writing my own sub to rewrite image URLs:

```
sub uri_for_image { 
    my ( $c, $path, @args ) = @_; 
    my $uri = $c->uri_for($path, @args);

  if (MyApp->config->{use_cdn}) {
    my $cdn = MyApp->config->{cdn_location};
    $uri = $path;
    $uri =~ s/^/$cdn/si;
  } 

return $uri;
}
```

But then I realized its gonna take a lot more work to get all the static files rerouted automatically. How should I go about setting a CDN url for static files?

I was looking into configuring [Static::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~mstrout/Catalyst-Plugin-Static-Simple-0.29/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/Static/Simple.pm) but it seems to only have settings for location of files locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think Catalyst actually can and should do for you here?

I'm afraid if you want to generate your own links which are outside the app, then you're pretty much on your own—there isn't anything Catalyst can really do or provide to help you here, is there?

Or do you just want `uri_for` to smash all paths starting in `/static` to point your CDN? As you can just wrap `uri_for` and make it do that?

I think your version (having a separate method) is cleaner and neater, but if all your static content is going onto the CDN, then just giving `uri_for` the behavior you want is reasonable.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way in which I could define the CDN in the config file and it just works. Yea I ended up implementing a uri_for_static method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Later in 2013 someone wrote the [`Catalyst::Plugin::ExternalURI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Catalyst-Plugin-ExternalURI/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/ExternalURI.pm) for this purpose.

From the synopsis section:

> ```
> use Catalyst qw/ ... ExternalURI ... /;
>
> __PACKAGE__->config(
>     externaluri => [
>         # Converts urls with the form of /static/css to start with another domain name 
>         { '^/static' => 'http://static.mydomain.com' },
>         ...
>         { 'MATCH' => 'REWRITE' }
>         or
>         { match => '^/static', rewrite => 'http://static.mydomain.com' },
>     ]
> );
> ```